# BLToolKit: Does it support IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, iqueryable, bltoolkit

Usually with BLToolKit I fetch data from DB in the following way:

```
using ( DbManager db = new MyDbManager() )
{
    IList<MyObjects> objects = db
        .SetCommand(query)//sometimes with additional parameters
        .ExecuteList<MyObjects>()
        ;
}
```

I would like to have ability to do the following:

```
using ( DbManager db = new MyDbManager() )
{
    IQueryable<MyObjects> qObjs = db
        .SetCommand(query)//sometimes with additional parameters
        .ExecuteQuery<MyObjects>()// here I don't want query actually to be executed
        ;

    // ... another logic, that could pass qObj into other part of program

    IList<MyObjects> objects = qObjs
        .Where(obj=>obj.SomeValue>=SomeLimit)    // here I want to put additional filters
        .ExecuteList()  // and only after that I wan't to execute query and fetch results
        ;
}
```

It is possible to workaround that with modifying orignal query-string (modify WHERE part), but sometimes it is pretty complicated.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks. Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using ( DbManager db = new MyDbManager() )
{
    IQueryable<MyObjects> qObjs = 
        from p in db.GetTable<MyObjects>()
        //sometimes with additional parameters
        select p;

    // ... another logic, that could pass qObj into other part of program

    IList<MyObjects> objects = qObjs
        .Where(obj=>obj.SomeValue>=SomeLimit)    // here I want to put additional filters
        .ToList()  // and only after that I wan't to execute query and fetch results
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have IQueriable , you have to use Linq. BlToolkit.Linq and BlToolkit.Data.Linq must import.

```
        IQueryable<DataModel.Object> query  = db.Object;


        If ((int)cmb_somthing.SelectedValue) > 0 {

            int ID  = (int)cmb_somthing.SelectedValue;
            query = query.Where(m=> m.ID = ID);

        }
        query = query.Where(m=> m.Date >= StartDate &&
                                m.Date <= EndDate);
```